# Resize animated GIF file using imagemagick with original FPS

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I wanted to resize animated gif file. I used the following command:

```
 .\convert.exe "d:\example.gif" -resize 600x400 "d:\exampleResult.gif"
```

And it was appeared that the result gif file is much slower than the original one. Even more, when I call convert without any additional parameters the result gif still slower than the original one:

```
.\convert.exe "d:\example.gif" "d:\exampleResult.gif"
```

How can I resize gif with original FPS?

Comment: If the gif has no delay set, then different viewer may set minimum delays. If the gif does have a delay, then you might try optimizing it as `convert image.gif -coalesce -resize 600x400 -layers optimize output.gif`

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. Resized gif is much slower than the original one.

Comment: Does your gif have a delay set in it?  The other way is to optimize the gif created by imagemagick using tools such as http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/. Post a link to your original animated gif. Also Identify what version and date of ImageMagick that you are using and on what platform (presumably Windows from you syntax, but what version of Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current delay between two frames using

`identify -verbose example.gif | grep Delay`.

This should give you something like `Delay: nx100` which means there is a `n/100`th of a second delay between two frames in the original gif.

Now if you would like to have the same frame rate, then just do it as follows

`convert -delay n example.gif example_new.gif`

If you want the frame rate to be faster, then use

`convert -delay m example.gif example_same.gif` where `m < n`.

And vice versa for a slower frame rate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are no such thing as Delay in the report. Don't know how to attach it. Its' huge

Comment: Well I just tried it on a gif on my Linux and it does return what I mentioned above. Can you confirm that you are executing the same commands?

Comment: Yes. I tried on this gif: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-J9nOy1ypilw/TmtQcZTMEbI/AAAAAAAAD1A/6vOhaQw5P9o/s781/Verre02_Micael_Reynaud_800_p0.gif

Comment: I tried it on your gif as well and it does work. I hope you are using Linux/OSX or rather any linux based OS.

Comment: You will only see `Delay:` (and many other lines besides) if you use `identify -verbose`, simple `identify` (no verbose flag) doesn't cut it